# Hash parameters to validate request

Tags: php, c++, api, http, hash

I have a socket Server, written C++, and an API Client in PHP to register new users for special locations.
To validate the request from the PHP Client, i will use an hash with HAMC with an unique key that are only know by the API Client and Socket Server.

The PHP Client send the content as JSON over HTTP POST, after that the Socket Server read and processe this.
That works fine.

Now, my questions.
I have three fields that i will hash:
message(String)
objectIDs(integer Array) 
type(String)

How i can create one hash for this three fields?
When i use JSON should it possible that the String of the JSON hasn’t the same sorting in PHP and C++(https://github.com/nlohmann/json) or more tabs, whitespaces or anything else?

And still as a little information the message can containes any characters.

Currently i use this

```
$str = "type=".$type. ";message=".$message;
foreach ($objectIDs as $index => $objectID) {
    $str .= ";objectID[" . $index . "]=" . $objectID;
}
//generate from a String a SHA256 hash with HMAC
$hash = getSignature($str);
```

Someone tells me that this sigining not unique and it should possible withe a special message that the system create a wrong hash. (But currently he isn‘t reachable)
In my tests i dind‘t can reproduce it. 
Now i hope someone other can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashes are equal if strings are equal.

That is, the aspect of that JSON is a bad choice for hashing is true: Semantically identical JSON objects can have different string representations.

On the Internet, you should, however, expect that also string representations can be complicated depending on the locale of both involved computers. If the locale is equal, everything is usually fine (choose UTF-8 everywhere is valid). However, I expect PHP to convert strings to the locale of the server. This can change the bit-representation of the string (similar to the JSON issue). Therefore, make sure that both work in the same locale and that such magic can never interefere with your system.

Comment: Thank you, that confirms my suspicions. 
But how i can create an unique hash for this?

Comment: Well, it is a bunch of work. Therefore, either make sure that every component uses the same encoding (e.g., utf8). iconv can be of help... http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php

Comment: No, the encoding isn´t the problem, i think.
My problem is, that i **should** possible to send a message with example a `,` and then the hash is inconclusive. The user said. I wait until he send me the example where I asked him for.
But thanks for your answer.